# Normal-like coordinates for weakly differentiable metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian $W^{2,p}$ metric, with $p>n/2$. Thus $g$ is at least continuous. At any point $P\in M$, do there exist local coordinates $x^i$ such that $g$ can be decomposed as $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + k_{ij}$, with $k_{ij} |x|^{-2}$ and $\partial k |x|^{-1}$ in $L^p$?

If $g$ were smooth, in normal coordinates, the metric expands as $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \frac13 R_{iklj}(P) x^k x^l + O(|x|^3)$. Clearly, this would be the kind of coordinates I want. It is also not hard to construct coordinates such that $g= \delta +k$ for some $k \in W^{2,p}$ and $k=0$ at $P$.

Comment: I suggest trying to see if this is true for simple examples, before trying to prove the general case. For example, $$g_{ij} = (1+|x|^{2-\alpha})\delta_{ij}$$ where $\alpha > -n/p$.

Comment: Well, that one clearly works in the original coordinates, but I'll try to think of a worse example. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. What you want to do is make the angular dependence singular b